# springboot + HBase + Redis junit test case

Tags: java, spring, hbase

I have a project with springboot + Hbase + Redis.

I want to write some junit test cases from a controller to a service to a HBaseDao, a whole flow operation. Because the project are committed by different teams in three cities, and every team has its env, so I cannot hardcode Hbase rootDir, zookeeper ip and port to test configuration file. But if I cannot hardcode these configurations, when loading the application, it cannot initialize HBase, so the case cannot run. I don't know how to workaround this. Or can Hbase run like H2 database, just in memory?